# Heap corruption error occurs when using initializer list

Tags: c++, heap-memory, initializer-list

I have a class, where I make an array on the heap. Later on I'm increasing the size of this array. When the class is constructed, I initialize the array. If I do this in the initializer list I get 'heap corruption error' when increasing the size of the array, but it doesn't occur if I don't use the initializer list.

Note that I haven't made a class with both those constructors, but only one of them at the time.
Why does it not work as expected when the initailizer list is used?

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector() noexcept;

    void push_back(const T& t);

private:
    T* m_arr;
    unsigned int m_size;
    unsigned int m_capacity;

    void realloc();

};

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector() noexcept
    : m_size(0), m_capacity(1) {
    m_arr = new T[m_capacity];
    // realloc() works fine with this constructor.
}

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector() noexcept
    : m_size(0), m_capacity(1), m_arr(new T[m_capacity]) {
    // Error occurs in realloc() with this constructor.
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& t) {
    if (m_size == m_capacity) {
        m_capacity <<= 1;
        realloc();
    }

    m_arr[m_size] = t;
    ++m_size;
}

template<typename T>
inline void Vector<T>::realloc() {
    T* newArr = new T[m_capacity];
    memcpy(newArr, m_arr, m_size * sizeof(T));
    delete[] m_arr; // Error occurs here with initializer list constructor.
    m_arr = newArr;
}
```

An example usage of the code where it crashes:

```
int main() {
    Vector vec;
    vec.push_back(0);
    vec.push_back(0); // Crashes here
    vec.push_back(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems ok to me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I changed the example. I copy-pasted this example from visual studio, and it does crash on my computer.

Comment: Members are initialized in the order they are declared *in the class*, not in the order you specify in the member initializer list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Yep, @UnholySheep is right. Works when I change the order

Comment: If compiler warnings are enabled, most compilers will warn about initializing member variable out-of-order in the constructor's initialization list from the order they are declared in the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with

```
template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector() noexcept
    : m_size(0), m_capacity(1), m_arr(new T[m_capacity]) {}
```

Lies in the way that member initializer lists work (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). In the section titled **"Initialization order"** it states:

> non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the
>   class definition

This means that due to your class definition `m_arr(new T[m_capacity])` gets executed *before* `m_capacity(1)` which means that the `new[]` uses an uninitialized variable, thus leading to *undefined behavior*